# What's a good way to store/load a word list with thousands of entries?

Tags: java, resources

I'm working on a project that requires a simple dictionary for checking spelling; it will be large, but will lack definitions. The solution we're currently working on has the base word list in a text file, and customizations (extra words, excluded words) in the DB.

The entire list needs to be loaded (best cached I think) for paginated display and customization using an existing JS widget, so what's the best way to store and load the base word list?

My initial thought was to have a text file with one word per line and write my own loader and cache object, but my boss suggested using a ResourceBundle to leverage the built-in caching. I'm thinking that could be done by using the words as keys with empty values and using the keyset of the bundle.

What would be the best solution to this?

Comment: Algorithm/approach discussions are safely on topic here. There's no need to migrate this question to [SO].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, the data structure your are looking for is called [TRIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

If you are looking to implement this in javascript, be sure to read [John Resig's blog on that subject](http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/). He evaluated several techniques for a similar problem, highly recommended.

Also, take a look at [this stackoverflow.com question to find java implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623892/where-do-i-find-a-standard-trie-based-map-implementation-in-java).

Comment: I'll definitely look into a trie or DAWG if we run into performance issues; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this for a language that does not already have dictionary files out there?  I'm not 100% certain, but I was pretty sure that the Aspell open sourced dictionaries were available to developers...

Comment: The app doing the work is written in Java and running on multiple platforms (Linux, Windows), so I don't know if this would be the right solution.